# How do I delete this folder?

Tags: windows-10

[image]

I'm trying to delete this folder and I'm unable to - I am told the folder or a file in it is open in another program. How do I delete this?

Comment: The first step would be to find out what's using the folder. Also, as per edits, windows dosen't use APKs. Do you have the same problem after you reboot?

Comment: *I am told the folder or a file in it is open in another program.* The whole folder I think. If it is a file, the folder's files would be partially deleted before a message. *How do I delete this?* Close the application which prevents deletion or wait until lock dissapeared (try to reboot). But check previously the deletion will not affect on the normal work (especially there are no some autoexecuted modules in this folder). The best choice is to find a process which prevents deletion.

Comment: Looks like this folder is open in some torrent or fileshare program. Do you have any of those installed on your computer? Also looks like it just has a single file which is being downloaded. I would either boot the computer in safe mode and delete it or close all the background apps and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by other users this might be a folder used by a download/torrent software. Try closing any open torrent/download apps running on the machine.
Alternatively try using the Unlocker tool: http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ and run it on this folder.
A 3rd option is to download and use the free Handle tool: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle to list all file handles. Then you can either close the app that has the handle opened or use ProcessExplorer: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer to close the handle.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other program/app folder in this folder?

If you make sure that the folder is no need to be used, try to reboot the machine and type `F8` to boot in `safe mode without any network connection`. Then, try to delete it.

Hope this can help you.